# How to share an object between threads to demonstrate that it is not thread-safe?

Tags: java, multithreading

MutableInteger is **not** considered a threadsafe class as it may often return stale values when called from different threads.

```
class MutableInteger{
    private int value;

    public int get(){
       return value;
    }

    public void set(int value){
       this.value=value;
    }   
}
```

And here is my thread implementation:- There is a main thread(main method) and MyThread is called from it.

```
class MyThread extends Thread{
    private int num;

    public void set(int num){
      this.num=num;
    }

    public void run(){
      MutableInteger mi=new MutableInteger();
      mi.set(num);
      System.out.println("Mythread "+mi.get());
    }
}

class MutableIntegerTest{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    MyThread t1=new MyThread();
    t1.set(10);     
    t1.start();
    MutableInteger mi=new MutableInteger();
    mi.set(99);
    System.out.println("Main thread" +mi.get());
    }
   }
```

Now here is what I fail to understand. For accessing the state variable `value` we need to use getter and setter methods of class `MutableInteger` so for every access we need to instantiate the `MutableInteger` class. Now as per theory, Every object has its own copy of instance variable. In my implementation both the threads access the `value` variable through `MutableInteger` instance only. It happens in my case that `value` is not shared between threads thus making my MutableInteger threadsafe.

What should I do to make the threads share the `value`? Should I make the object public so that I could use the same object in both the threads? But would this not publicize the object to all available classes and threads?

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What's your problem? There is no shared data other than `MyThread.num` and that is only ever set when the thread is not yet started. Or rather: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Consider the AtomicInteger.

Comment: So how should I access the same instance from more than 1 thread. Should I make the instance public or should I pass the instance from 1 thread to another??

Comment: Given the MutableInteger class, I simply want to know how to write a thread class for it.

Comment: ..._I simply want to know how to write a thread class for it_.  What does that mean?  What would a "thread class for it" do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to test your `MutableInteger` to see with your own eyes that it is not thread-safe, you must **share an object between the threads**. If each of the threads creates its own instancef of `MutableInteger`, then as you noticed, you are not actually testing that particular thing because it is only accessed by the single thread that created it.

So you need to create an instance, and have the two threads both use it. For example:

A runnable object (it's preferable to using a class that extends `Thread`):

```
class MutableIntegerTester implements Runnable {

    private int num;
    private MutableInteger mutableInteger;

    public MutableIntegerTester(int num, MutableInteger mutableInteger) {
        this.num = num;
        this.mutableInteger = mutableInteger;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        for ( int i = 0; i < 1000; i++ ) {
            mutableInteger.set(mutableInteger.get() + num);
        }
        System.out.println(mutableInteger.get());
    }

}
```

Note that I changed the `run` method into something that will give you a better chance to see the lack of safety. You have both a non-atomic read and addition, and usage of a "stale" (non-volatile) variable.

To share the object, use:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MutableInteger sharedObject = new MutableInteger();
    MutableIntegerTester tester1 = new MutableIntegerTester(10, sharedObject);
    MutableIntegerTester tester2 = new MutableIntegerTester(99, sharedObject);
    new Thread(tester1).start();
    new Thread(tester2).start();
}
```

Now, if the mutableInteger was thread safe, you'd expect the result to always print 109000. But of course it won't. And it will probably print a different number every run and even different numbers for the different threads sometimes.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question "how to share variables beetween threads", you only show how to get thread-related errors, so your answer is useless.

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki It actually does - especially in light of the OP's comments explaining what he was actually asking about.

Comment: Note, that the way this test is written is not really correct.
`mutableInteger.set(mutableInteger.get() + num);` is not fine, because when one thread gets the value of mutableInteger, summarises it with num and sets the result back, another threads can do this several times. So, even if ImmutableInteger will be completely threadsafe a test above won't pass, as it brings some race-conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Your current code is thread-safe, but in general your classes are not thread-safe. It's safe to use `t1.set()` before `t1.start()` as thread starting introduces happens-before edge (from inside the started thread you can see all the events occurred in the starter thread before `Thread.start()` invocation). However if you call `t1.set()` after the thread start, it's not guaranteed that the thread will ever see that new value.

The same for `MutableInteger`. Currently you don't share `MutableInteger` instances between threads, thus they work fine. However if you share, it's not guaranteed that changes will be visible. Consider, for example, your `run()` method:

```
public void run(){
  MutableInteger mi=new MutableInteger();
  mi.set(num);
  System.out.println("Mythread "+mi.get());
}
```

Currently the JIT-compiler can understand that `MutableInteger` object has no side effect and optimize out it object at all effectively converting your method to:

```
public void run(){
  System.out.println("Mythread "+num);
}
```

Even without JIT-compiler optimizations there are still memory visibility problems (the `MutableInteger` object can be cached in the CPU core L1 cache and other CPU core won't see the updated value) as well as CPU instructions reordering. So without having the `volatile` keyword it cannot be guaranteed that another thread will see the changes. Adding the `volatile` keyword you effectively convert your `MutableInteger` to already existing `AtomicInteger` (which has single int volatile field inside and also much more handy methods along with setter and getter).

Answer (score 0):

**Dissenting View**

I would say that the `MutableInteger` class *is* thread safe.

When I claim that a class is thread safe, I mean that there is no way in which overlapped calls to its methods from different threads can cause the class or an instance of the class to violate its API contract.

What is the API contract of `MutableInteger`?

The OP doesn't say, but any reasonable programmer can see what it does.

I would argue that as long as get() returns either the initial value, 0, or some value that previously was set(); and as long as get() never reverts to returning some older value in thread `t` after it has once returned a newer value in the same thread `t`, then I would argue that the class is behaving in a reasonable way.

Java library classes that guarantee any kind of *happens before* relationship between method calls usually spell out those guarantees in their documentation.  E.g., from the javadoc of the `java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue` interface:

> ...actions in a thread prior to placing an object into a `BlockingQueue` *happen-before* actions subsequent to the access or removal of that element from the `BlockingQueue` in another thread.

I don't see any such claims made for the `MutableInteger` class, so I would not call it "broken" if, for example, it behaved like an ordinary int instead of behaving like a `volatile` int.